# iOS app binary doubled in size in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, llvm-clang

My iOS app needs to be very small in order to be downloaded at events with low cell reception and no wi-fi. My app used to be 1.8 MB on the App Store, and it took me a long time to get it that small. The binary itself (inside the .ipa file) was 1.6 MB uncompressed.

I built the latest version of my app in Xcode 5, and all of a sudden the binary itself is much bigger. The app is 3.9 MB on the App Store. The binary itself is 3.4 MB uncompressed.

I haven't changed my build settings, nor my targets (armv7 and armv7s only). The code is mainly C++ but also Obj-C.

Why would this happen?

Comment: I'd start by doing a file-by-file comparison of the .app bundles to see what has been added or has grown.

Comment: @BergQuester thanks for the suggestion – it's the binary itself which has grown. I'm trying various approaches to diffing the two binaries (hex diff, strings diff) but nothing is jumping out at me.

Comment: Apple's Documentation states "A future version of Xcode will let you create a single app that supports the 32-bit runtime on iOS 6 and later, and that supports the 64-bit runtime on iOS 7." Maybe that'll help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with our game after upgrading to Xcode 5. Using `file` and `otool` I get the following results:

**Xcode 4 build**

```
> file Game.app/Game
Game.app/Game: Mach-O executable arm
> otool -h Game.app/Game
Game.app/Game:
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
 0xfeedface      12          9  0x00           2    29       3332 0x00218085
```

**Xcode 5 build**

```
> file Game.app/Game
Game.app/Game: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
Game.app/Game (for architecture armv7): Mach-O executable arm
Game.app/Game (for architecture cputype (12) cpusubtype (11)):  Mach-O executable arm
> otool -h Game.app/Game
Game.app/Game (architecture armv7):
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
 0xfeedface      12          9  0x00           2    32       3588 0x00218085
Game.app/Game (architecture armv7s):
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
 0xfeedface      12         11  0x00           2    32       3588 0x00218085
```

To prevent Xcode 5 from building a fat (both `armv7` and `armv7s`) binary, go to Build Settings for the target and set the Architectures entry explicitly to only `armv7` (the default is `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)`).

Answer (score 2):

Try building it for armv7 architecture only.  I worked on a project where app size was a priority, and the only way for us to get the app down below the 50 MB cutoff was to remove armv7s.

Comment: FYI, the limit has raised to 100 MB now.

Comment: also FYI, that limit is for cellular networks **only**, on wifi networks there is no size limitation.

Answer (score 2):

I’d guess that the app has now been built for both 32- and 64-bit (arm64). You can verify this 
by running `file /path/to/TheApp.app/TheApp`. Also see Apple’s “[64-Bit Transition Guide for Cocoa Touch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)” for more information on the new architecture.

Comment: Unfortunately no, as I mentioned in my question it's still armv7 and armv7s.

Answer (score 0):

Too see exactly what's inside and compare the 2 ipa files (old vs. new), just change the suffix to .zip, unzip them to list the contents, and perhaps run the lipo command on the executable binary to see how many architectures were included.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but I already addressed both of your ideas in my original question.